# Change UIPopover background

Tags: objective-c, ipad, uipopovercontroller

I'm looking to change the popovers border. It's just a solid flat color, so no image required.
Is there a property that I can tap in to, or will I have to subclass?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Changing the look of a popover being shown via a UIPopoverController isn't supported.  I wouldn't even try, as you may do a lot of work to reverse-engineer UIPopoverController, only to have it break in a subsequent software update.

Comment: gaah that's terrible. I'm surprised this isn't more of an issue for people. This is going to seriously effect my design. Back to the drawing board I suppose.

Comment: Is this still true? I've seen some custom ones around. But I think they were made with frameworks such as unity

Comment: Apple still supplies no API for customizing the look of UIPopoverController's associated view.  In fact, there isn't even API to access that view.  If you want the behavior of UIPopoverController but want a different look, you'll pretty much need to implement your own similar class from scratch.  I would strongly recommend against attempting to modify or subclass UIPopoverController itself.