# PopOver Frame Color

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ipad, uipopovercontroller

How can I change the PopOver's frame color ?

Description : By default the frame of popOver is black and same with the popOver arrow.

Default One :
[image: This is by default color of my PopOver.]

I want this frame like this(in green or some other color.
[image]

EDIT : on the top bar I want two titles(one sub-title). Is it possible and how ?
[image]

How can I do it ?

Regards !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I am concerned, there is no way of doing that

EDIT: please check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2552686/how-to-customize-style-a-uipopovercontroller), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4110089/change-uipopover-background), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4710436/remove-border-for-uipopovercontroller) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3399861/change-the-bordercolor-of-uipopovercontroller)

Comment: Thanks for a quick response Felipe but are you sure ?

Comment: yes, and I just edited the answer with some references. Actually, this question has been asked a lot here in SO.

Comment: Yeah , thanks. :-) One more question - Can I have two titles (Like One Title , another one as a sub-title) of a pop-over ?

Comment: I dont think you can do that either, but now I am just guessing :)

Comment: Please see the EDIT part of question. I've got this screenshot of popOver. So I think we can do this ?

Comment: sorry, I don't know the answer to that. But you should have created another question for that ;)

Comment: Ok , now I'll do that. Thanks :-)

Answer (score 0):

Yes i am finding to change PopOver Border color... but i think we can't set other color...
And about title on PopOver,yes we can set two title like this......On NavigationBar add two labels... or take one label and make it numberoflines 2 or 3